# Responsive CSS Ribbon

Tags: css

I am trying to create a css ribbon, responsive would be great. Otherwise I'll just show it on desktop.

Here is the link to my dev site: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/xpect/

If you take a look at the the orange callout area underneath the header images, I'd like to have to have it look like the attached image.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The community can definitely help you more when you show what you have tried :) [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I was hoping that the code could be viewed via the site link I posted. If you use dev tools or firebug you will see that I have added css ribbons there, it's just the same colour as the background. Is this not helpful enough? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it with before and after pseudo classes and the border triangle trick. Your HTML would be super simple:

```
<div class="ribbon">...</div>
```

And your CSS would be this:

```
.ribbon { 
    background: #f47d19; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 50px; 
    width: 300px; 
    margin:0 25px; //Half of height
}
.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after { 
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    border: 25px solid transparent; //Half of height
    border-top-color: #f47d19; 
    border-bottom-color: #f47d19; 
    z-index: -1; //Place triangles behind div
}
.ribbon:before { 
    left: -25px; //Half of height
}
.ribbon:after { 
    right: -25px; //Half of height
}
```

### [Fiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Haukf/)

Then for the responsive part, you would simply change the width, height, margin and position properties to match whatever resolution you are at.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, you can use the `.img-responsive` class to the image. If not, try to add `height:auto` in css for that. That'll make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

|                  parent div                      |

| div float left (image of >) | div float left (content) | div float left (img <) |

|div style clear both |

this way you can throw all of your content into the middle div and have the whole thing responsive

could also do this with a basic table